# An invalid form control with name="" is not focusable with HTML <template> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a wizard form. In which content div is split into four section, each section is wrapped inside the template tag. To show current target as a active section i have written a css as follow,

```
section {
    display: none;
}

section:target {
    display: block;
  }
```

To show template based on current target i have written Javascript as below,

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
   
    if(e.target.URL.includes("#") == false)
    { 
        window.location.href = "index.html#wizard-p-0";
    } 
    var splUri = e.target.URL.split("#");
    var actsplUri = splUri[1].split("-");
    
    var contentDiv = document.querySelector("#content-div");

    var template = document.querySelector('#section-'+actsplUri[2]);
    
    var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
        
    contentDiv.appendChild(clone);

    if(actsplUri[2] > 0){
        var btn_prevs = document.getElementById('btn-prevs');  
        btn_prevs.setAttribute("aria-disabled", "flase");
    }
    else{
        var btn_prevs = document.getElementById('btn-prevs');  
        btn_prevs.setAttribute("aria-disabled", "true");
    }
   
})
```

It is working perfectly. whenever i click next button form action will be updated with target element id.(Next is a submit button)

I have a  tag for previous button. Whenever i click  previous button the previous target element id will be found and based on that i will clone the .

Once i click next button after clicking previous button it shows the error "An invalid form control with name="state" is not focusable". It is because this field is required field, to avoid this error only i written some template  tags in html.

Kindly help me to resolve this...

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wizard Form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/material-design-iconic-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="assets/images/shopping.png" alt="" width="700" height="800">
        </div>
        <form action="#wizard-p-0" id="form-wizard">
            <div id="wizard" role="application" class="wizard clearfix">
                <div class="steps clearfix" id="steps-div">
                    <ul role="tablist" id="ul-steps">
                        <li role="tab" aria-disabled="false" class="litag first checked current" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="wizard-p-0">
                            <a id="wizard-t-0" href="#wizard-p-0">
                                <span class="current-info audiable">current step: </span>
                                <span class="number">1.</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="tab" aria-disabled="false" class="litag done" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="wizard-p-1">
                            <a id="wizard-t-1" href="#wizard-p-1">
                                <span class="number">2.</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="tab" aria-disabled="false" class="litag done" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="wizard-p-2">
                            <a id="wizard-t-2" href="#wizard-p-2">
                                <span class="number">3.</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="tab" aria-disabled="false" class="litag done" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="wizard-p-3">
                            <a id="wizard-t-3" href="#wizard-p-3">
                                <span class="number">4.</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="content clearfix" id="content-div">

                <!-- SECTION 1 -->
                <template id="section-0">
                <h4></h4>
                <section id="wizard-p-0">
                    <div id="error-section1"></div>
                    <div class="form-row form-group">
                        <div class="form-holder">
                            <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-holder">
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name" id="company_name">
                        </div>  
                       <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="address">Address *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street address" style="margin-bottom: 20px" name="add_line1" id="add_line1" required>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City, State etc. (optional)" name="add_line2" id="add_line2">
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="city">Town / City *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="pin_code">
                                Postcode / Zip *
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pin_code" id="pin_code" required>
                        </div>
                </section>
            </template>

                <!-- SECTION 2 -->
                <template id="section-1">
                <h4></h4>
                <section id="wizard-p-1">
                    <div id="error-section2"></div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="state">State *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" id="state" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="country">Country *</label>
                        <div class="form-holder">
                            <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" required> 
                                <option value="IN" class="option">India</option>
                                <option value="USA" class="option">United States</option>
                                <option value="UK" class="option">United Kingdom</option>
                            </select>
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-row form-group">
                        <div class="form-holder">
                            <label for="phone_no">Phone *</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-holder">
                            <label for="email_add">Email Address *</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_add" id="email_add" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" size="100" required> 
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-row" style="margin-bottom: 18px">
                        <label for="order_notes">Order Notes</label>
                        <textarea name="order_notes" id="order_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Note about your order, eg. special notes fordelivery." style="height: 149px" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="create_account"> Create an account?
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </template>

                 <!-- SECTION 3 -->
                 <template id="section-2">
                 <h4></h4>
                 <section id="wizard-p-2">
                     <div class="product">
                         <div class="item">
                             <div class="left">
                                 <a href="#" class="thumb">
                                     <img src="assets/images/item-1.png" alt="">
                                 </a>
                                 <div class="purchase">
                                     <h6>
                                         <a href="#">Low Table/Stool</a>
                                     </h6>
                                     <span>x4</span>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <span class="price">Rs.29</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="item">
                             <div class="left">
                                 <a href="#" class="thumb">
                                     <img src="assets/images/item-2.png" alt="">
                                 </a>
                                 <div class="purchase">
                                     <h6>
                                         <a href="#">Set of 3 plates</a>
                                     </h6>
                                     <span>x2</span>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <span class="price">Rs.124</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </section>
                 </template>

                <!-- SECTION 4 -->
                <template id="section-3">
                    <section id="wizard-p-3">   
                    <div class="checkout">
                        
                         <div class="checkbox-circle">
                            <label class="active">
                                <input type="radio" name="billing_method" id="direct-payment" value="Direct bank transfer" checked>Direct bank transfer>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                <div class="tooltip">
                                    Make your payment directly into our bank account. Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. 
                                </div>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="billing_method" id="check-payment" value="Check payments">Check payments
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                <div class="tooltip">
                                    Please send a check to Store Name, Store Street, Store Town, Store State / County, Store Postcode.
                                </div>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="billing_method" id="cash-payment" value="Cash on delivery">Cash on delivery
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                <div class="tooltip">
                                    Pay with cash upon delivery.
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                         <div class="total">
                             <span class="heading">Subtotal</span>
                             <span class="total-price">$364</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </section>
                </template>
                </div>

                <div class="actions clearfix">
                    <ul role="menu" aria-label="pagination">
                        <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true">
                            <a href="" id="btn-prevs" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
                        </li>
                        <li aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" class style>
                            <input type="submit" value="Next" id="btn-next" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="false">
                        </li>
                        <li aria-hidden="true" id="li-finish" class="disable">
                            <a href="#finish" id="btn-finish" role="menuitem">Place Order</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML? It's hard to tell what's going on without the HTML.

Comment: You misspelled 'false' in your btn_prevs.setAttribute line. Not to solve the issue, just letting you know.

Comment: @chingucoding included html code

Comment: @matt thank you misspell is corrected